# PHP: How to create and register class at runtime

Tags: php, class, laravel, runtime

Is there any official/recommended way to declare/define/register a new class at runtime in PHP?

What I basically want to do is generating Classes based on the definition stored in a database, both properties and methods.

I have found some article/threads, but all of them are actually old, so I was wondering if it exists some elegant/efficient way to do it. My surprise is that there is no so much information about this as I thought.

Is it so bad? As far as I know, PHP always saves the class definition in memory so I don't see any problem in declaring the class at runtime as it's basically the same result, but maybe I'm wrong.

I think is not relevant right now, but I'm working with Laravel in this project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
<?php

$foobar = "foobar";

eval("class $foobar {" .
        "function __construct(\$i) {" .
                "echo \"Dark magic ritual complete. \$i virgins sacrificed to satan.\"; " .
        "}" . 
" }");

$evil = new $foobar(5);


echo "<br /><br />";

var_dump($evil);
```

Produces:

> Dark magic ritual complete. 5 virgins sacrificed to satan.
>
> object(foobar)#1 (0) { }

I'm not going to lecture you on semantics, but this is a terribly bad idea and you should reconsider using classes to facilitate what the database records need. A class by itself is not special, but using a class to handle a database entry is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I think he is creating classes based on values stored in the database, not something equivalent as ORM.

Comment: Either I need a lot more caffeine or "declare/define/register" has a different meaning to me. It's trivial to instantiate a `new`, which would indicate he wants something more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I actually need is to work with dynamic entities, as the different users should be able to create their own objects with its attributes. I have decided not to use Entity-Attribute-Value "anti"-pattern because of the complexity and all the cons it has, so I thought this could be a better solution. I tried to ask which was the best approach/pattern for this in another question but It didn't work as it was not a Php specifc question. So, which would be the recommendation for this?

Comment: As I've shown, you can use `new $foobar` where `$foobar` is a class name to instantiate an existing class. In an anecdotal experience, I've had a User Password table where a user's password could have many different kinds of encryption algorithms. To solve password checking, I wrote a `Password` interface and then `PasswordMd5` `PasswordSha256` classes that implement the Interface and instantiate based on a complementary `encryption` column. `$goodPassword = new $encryption()->is($inputPassword)`.

Comment: That question, by the way, is the one you should have been asking. :P

Comment: Jaw but as you said it's a really bad idea, isn't? So which is the best solution for this scenario? :(

Comment: No, my idea is fine. It's only a bad idea to use `eval()`, ever. If you just want to instantiate classes based on database records, what I've said is perfectly correct. Build an interface, store class names in the db, instantiate at need.

Comment: Jaw maybe I also need more caffeine, but in you example you use eval()... Am i missing anything?

Comment: I'm talking about the second one I gave to you after your first comment.

Comment: @Jaw.sh it's not per definition a _bad_ idea to use `eval`, you have to secure the environment `eval` runs in. If you know the security risks `eval` offers, you can secure it like any other function, just don't call it directly and assume the arguments given never contain any harmful code.

Comment: But if I understood you, in that example you have the Encryption Classes written in a .php, the problem here is that I can not have the classes written, as I don't know which classes exists or will exists. Maybe one user define Account and Contact Objects (classes) and another House and Room Objects.

Comment: If you have no idea what classes can exist there is a fundamental design problem in your application.

Comment: No, there is no design problem, it's just more a PaaS than an Application. Users can define and manage their own objects.